# How to implement toolbar collapse/expend with frgagment?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-coordinatorlayout

I want to implement the collapse and expend on the scroll flag **SCROLL** and **ENTER_ALWAYS** the toolbar by scrolling the recyclerview inside the fragment layout. In my case I am using the toolbar and bottom navigation with FrameLayout to contain each fragment. So inside my HomeFragment, I am using recylcerview.

**Here is my main layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout>

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context=".ui.milio.main.MainActivity">

        <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
                android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="@color/colorWhite"
                android:padding="@dimen/dimen_12dp">

                <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                    android:id="@+id/collapse_tool_bar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                        android:id="@+id/main_tool_bar"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_medium"
                            android:text="Home"
                            android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                            android:textSize="24sp" />

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/ivSearchIcon"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dimen_7dp"
                            android:layout_toStartOf="@id/ivAddNewPostIcon"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_search" />

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/ivAddNewPostIcon"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_post" />

                    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
                </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
            </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
        </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/main_frame_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
            app:itemIconTint="@drawable/tab_color"
            app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
            app:menu="@menu/navigation" />
    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

**Here is my fragment layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout>

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorLayoutBackground"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".ui.milio.home.HomeFragment">

        <androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
            android:id="@+id/swrNewsFeed"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/rvNewsFeedFragment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="false"/>
        </androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Things you've done wrong is

1. Scrolling view (in your case `FrameLayout`) should be inside `CoordinatorLayout`
2. To get collapsing effect, you have to set a fixed height of `AppBarLayout`
3. You have to set collapse mode for `Toolbar`
4. You have to set scrolling behavior to the the scrolling view (in your case `FrameLayout`)

Changed sample code can be as following:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <!--Changes here-->
        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_150sdp"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:padding="@dimen/_12sdp">

            <!--Changes here-->
            <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/collapse_tool_bar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

                <!--Changes here-->
                <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/main_tool_bar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                        android:text="Home"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textSize="24sp" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/ivSearchIcon"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/_150sdp"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_7sdp"
                        android:layout_toStartOf="@id/ivAddNewPostIcon"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_search" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/ivAddNewPostIcon"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/_150sdp"
                        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_plus" />

                </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
            </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

        <!--Changes here-->
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/main_frame_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_anchor="@id/appBarLayout"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom"
            app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior" />

    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
        app:menu="@menu/create_task_menu" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You saved my day. Thanks so much for your answer. Thumb Up. Good day!!!

Comment: However, whenever, I pressed to any other fragment, it still collapse. How to reset it collapse ?

Comment: `appBarLayout.setExpanded(true/false)` this will work for that.